# Lubuntu with an Ubuntu desktop: system menu not visible 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, tweak

These are the steps I followed:

1. install Lubuntu 14.04
2. install Ubuntu desktop 14.04
3. install ubuntu-tweak-tool
4. install unity-tweak-tool (this did not work, it asked me to install missing packages)
5. install gnome-tweak-tool
6. download and install the macbuntu theme from www.noobslab.com

*Result*: when I start the Ubuntu desktop, the system menu in the upper right corner isn't visible and I have to shut down/restart from a terminal.

Can anyone help?

Comment: No comprendo... Can you number your steps?
1. I install Lubuntu...  Computer works
2. I install updates...  Computer works
3. ...  ;)

Comment: 1. tengo lubuntu instalado
2. instale ubuntu desktop 14.04
3. instale ubuntu-tweak-tool
4. instale unity-tweak-tool
no funcionaron, me pide instale paquetes faltantes

5. instale gnome-tweak-tool
6. descargue el tema de www.noobslab.com, cambien el tema a mac 

cuando inicio con el escritorio de ubuntu no se como cerrar la sesión pues no aparece en la esquina superior derecha el boton de apagar

Comment: Don't add more comments, [edit] your question to add more information. (Capisco un po 'di spagnolo, perché io parlo un po' d'italiano)

Answer (score 0):

The mac doesn't have a system menu in the upper right corner so please uninstall the mac theme *first*...

We'll take it from there and update your question and my answer to take you further.